# Order property of ActionFilter, from lowest to greatest or vice versa?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter, order-of-execution

I defined two ActionFilters:

```
[DefaultResources(Order = 2)]
[RenderTemplate(Order = 1)]
```

And to my surprise DefaultResources is executed BEFORE RenderTemplate. But according to MSDN documentation it should work vice versa:

```
[Filter1(Order = 2)]
[Filter2(Order = 3)]
[Filter3(Order = 1)]
public void Index()
{
    View("Index");
}
```

> In this example, action filters would
>   execute in the following order:
>   Filter3, Filter1, and then Filter2.

I'm using .NET 4. And comparing by method OnActionExecuted. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[image: Last-in First-out order]

This is the answer I was looking for. Order of OnActionExecuted is reversed order of OnActionExecuting...

Comment: Why is it Filter1, Filter2, Filter3 (as shown in the diagram of your response) and not Filter3, Filter1, Filter2 (per the apparent intent of your "order =" attribute arguments from your question?

Comment: So in other words the `Order` is `ASC` in `OnActionExecuting` and `DESC` in `OnActionExecuted`

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what each filter implements.

If DefaultResource implements OnActionExecuting or OnActionExecuted then it will fire first if RenderTemplate does not.

For more details see:

http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/09/custom-ordering-of-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc/

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx

"The ASP.NET MVC framework will call the OnActionExecuting method of your action filter before it calls any action method that is marked with your action filter attribute. Similarly, the framework will call the OnActionExecuted method after the action method has finished. "

Comment: The only methods implemeted are OnActionExecuted in both ActionFilters, as I wrote before. Another difference, which could possible (but IMHO very unlikely) cause this is, that DefaultResource is implemented in MVC application project and the other one is defined in linked project.

Comment: For the more I can definetly say, that changing of Order value makes order different. E.g. DefaultResource(Order=2) RenderTemplate(Order=3) the first executed was again RenderTemplate, it doesn't make sense having read msdn and gregshackles...

Answer (score 0):

See [Filtering in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx#sectionToggle4) for a full explanation of what determines the order of execution of action filters and their methods.

Regarding `OnResultExecuted`, which you said your filters are using, see the following:

> The `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)`, `OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext)`, and `OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext)` filters run in forward order. The `OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext)`, `OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext)`, and `OnException(ExceptionContext)` filters run in reverse order.

The ordering is actually quite complex, so take a look at the article for more details.