# Force two ActionFilter attributes to be used in conjunction with one another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, action-filter

I had three Authorization Attributes that contained code to check that the content being requested actually exists.  I decided to avoid repeating myself in each, by creating a new attribute called `QuizExistsAttribute`.

I wish to run this before my other Authorization attributes.

Now that I have this extra attribute, I wish to ensure that the original attributes that I was using, aren't used without this new attribute - because I want the check to be made before anything else.

My other authorization attributes that rely on the logic of `QuizExistsAttribute` being performed are:

- `ActiveQuizTakerSessionAtrribute`
- `AuthorizeQuizAdminAttribute`

So in my code I will be using them like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Start of a quiz
/// </summary>
/// <param name="urlId"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[QuizExists] // Check that quiz exists
[ActiveQuizTakerSession] // Check that they have an active session for this quiz
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult QuizQuestion(string urlId)
{
    // Code here after checks
}
```

Is there a way to enforce that `ActiveQuizTakerSession` is used injunction with (and following) the `QuizExists` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the order in which each attribute is executed:

```
[QuizExists(Order = 1)] // Check that quiz exists
[ActiveQuizTakerSession(Order = 2)] // Check that they have an active session for this quiz
[HttpGet]
```

Here's a good reference to help you further:

[Order property of ActionFilter, from lowest to greatest or vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152420/order-property-of-actionfilter-from-lowest-to-greatest-or-vice-versa)