# ActionFilters not executing in expected order, possibly an autofac issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I have 2 action filters, where I need the one to explicitly execute before the other. I have not had any luck with getting them to cooperate and execute in the order expected.

```
public class RedirectSingleAttribute : ActionFilterAttrbute {
   public UrlHelper Url { get; set; } // <= injected in OnActivating
   public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExectuedContext filterContext) {
       /* ... magic ... */
   }
}

public class JsonRedirectAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        /* ... magic ... */
    }
}

public class SearchController : Controller {
    [RedirectSingle(Order = 1)]
    [JsonRedirect(Order = 2)]
    public ActionResult Query(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        /* some code */
    }
}
```

My module looks like...

```
/* ... */
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
/* ... */
builder.RegisterType<RedirectSingleAttribute>();
builder.RegisterType<JsonRedirectAttribute>()
    .OnActivating(c => c.Instance.Url = c.Context.Resolve<UrlHelper>());
/* ... */
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
```

I put a breakpoint on both of the `OnActionExecuted` methods, and the `JsonRedirectAttribute` consistently keeps executing first. I tried reversing the order, and also tried using the `AsActionFilterFor` with no success.

Removing the attributes from the action method, and using the autofac registration style, the attributes do not execute at all.

```
/* this ended up not working all, i.e. the action filters were never invoked */
builder.RegisterType<RedirectSingleAttribute>()
    .AsActionFilterFor<SearchController>(c => c.Query(default(SearchCriteria)), 1);
builder.RegisterType<JsonRedirectAttribute>()
    .OnActivating(c => c.Instance.Url = c.Context.Resolve<UrlHelper>())
    .AsActionFilterFor<SearchController>(c => c.Query(default(SearchCriteria)), 2);
```

Comment: Though I believe I tried reversing the order, that does not appear to be the case, as I've just tried reversing the order and they execute appropriately. This post help to explain it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152420/order-property-of-actionfilter-from-lowest-to-greatest-or-vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the  the "Scope" enumeration value along with the "Order" property. This msdn link might throw some light : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers as links may break.